# Logical Operator always stays true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

What I want is to compare current url with my cookie array which would contain all the URL's a user has visited so it would compare that whether the array contains the current link or not so if not it would push that new link to the array and would again recreate the cookie with the new array which would contain the new pushed link so what I am facing right now is that everytime the if function which checks for the unique link always comes true I am not sure that what's the problem?

Can you people please have a look over it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

var url = window.location.href;
var pathname = new URL(url).pathname;
var jsonObj = [];

//jsonObj.push("test");

var x = readCookie('vid_cookies');
if (x) {
var res = x.split(",");
console.log(res);
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    if (pathname != res[i]) {
        alert("IS NOT EQUAL");
    //res.push(pathname);
    //var joinedArray = res.join(",");
    //console.log(joinedArray);
    //createCookie('vid_cookies',joinedArray,7);
    //var z = readCookie('vid_cookies');
    //console.log(z)
    }
}
} else {
    jsonObj.push(pathname);
createCookie('vid_cookies',jsonObj,7);
}


//alert(jsonObj);

</script>
```

Here is the Array as :

```
["/evercookie-master/yahoo.html", "/evercookie-master/facebook.html", "/evercookie-master/facebook.html", "/evercookie-master/facebook.html"]
```

Comment: That's not possible. A string cannot be equal and not equal to another string at the same time (or maybe I misunderstood the question). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling : Yeah sorry about that that sounded a bit weird What I want is that I can see that my `pathname` and `res[i]` has values which are equal to  each other and still the function executes which shouldn't be the case as I am checking there for the values which are not equal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not correct. If you want to add a value to an array only if it doesn't exist yet, you have to check **all** elements before you add it.

In your code you are adding the value as soon as *any* of the element doesn't match. That will always be the case of course because out `n` elements, `n - 1` will not match.

One way to do it would be to use `Array#every`:

```
if (res.every(x => x !== pathname)) {
 // add to array and set cookie
}
```

Alternatively you could convert the array to a `Set`, always add the value and set the cookie. The `Set` will automatically dedupe the values:

```
var res = new Set(x.split(","));
res.add(pathname);
res = Array.from(res);
```

Comment: It's still a bit confusing for me in understanding. Can you please make it sound simple?

Comment: At the moment you are basically only checking whether the value is equal to the first element in the array, and based in that you are deciding whether to add it or not. I.e. if your array is `[1,2]` and the value to check is `1`, the first comparison will be `2 != 1` which is true and you will add the value and set the cookie. You have to look at all elements in the array and only add it if all elements are not equal.

Comment: So to add more to your words exactly that function won't go beyond to check for more right if it executes at the starting elements? And so everytime will keep doing so...!

Comment: Is that about the same in every language or just in JavaScript?

Comment: First unless you `break` the loop it will still continue to check all elements, but at the time the second element is checked the value was already added to the array. This is a logic error, you'd have the same issue in any language.