# Javascript Variable Unchanged

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let errors = false;

// Check for errors in any single payload
for (let result of results) if (result.status === "error") {
    errors = true;
    errorMessage = result.message;
    console.log(errors) // logs out "true"
} else {
    errors = false;
}

console.log(errors) // logs out "false"

// If error exists, alert user
if (errors === true) {
   console.log(errors);
   alert('Error Requesting Monitor Data!\n'+errorMessage)
} else {
    console.log(errors); // logs out "false"
}
```

New to JavaScript, coming from Python/Scala. In the code above, errors outside of the for loop scope never modifies to `true`. What am I not understanding about the scope of variables and modification of values?

Comment: It would only be set to `true` if `result.status === "error"` is `true`. Is that the case?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, I see the following in the console: x3 true, and then a false from the second conditional.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/8hhytjbf/ . If your actual code is like this one (and all variables are defined), then it will work as expected. It certainly doesn't appear to be a scope issue.

Comment: `results` is undefined, so it will just error. (Hint provide a [mcve])

Comment: @TylerMills In the second `if` you only check if the last object in `results` has an error or not

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: Good catch.

Comment: Reminds me of the question I answered yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934042/218196 .

Comment: There are methods in `Array.prototype` that allow to avoid manual looping. For example `const hasError = results.some(result => result.status === 'error')`  of `const maybeFirstError = results.find(result => result.status === 'error')`

Comment: You can also use if (errors) ... that's shorthand for (errors === true). If errors was a number any non-zero value would be result in if path being executed. If errors was a string with > 0 characters, then it would follow if path too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is largely irrelevent.

Since you set `errors = false` in the `else` part of the loop, you are essentially checking to see if the *last* thing you test is an error.

You go through the loop and flip the result to `true` or `false` each time. It ends up with a value describing the last thing.

If your goal is to test if "one or more" of the collection is an error, then you need to **remove the else branch**.

That way it starts off as `false` and might get flipped to `true` if there are errors but will never get flipped back.

Comment: Ah shit, rookie mistake. You're right. What was happening was that I was reassigning the value of `errors` back to `false` when a successful payload was mixed in with a bad payloads from the endpoint. So that "else" conditional in the first block should be removed.